# TFS 2017 TF31002

Tags: tfs

Apparently we have a configuration issue with TFS 2017 11.0.60315.1

The team project collection(s) are online, but I get TF31002 error when I try to connect from my client **AND** the server.  e.g. click "Change URLs" and "Test"

I also get HTTP code 404: Not Found when I click "Group Membership" or "Administer Security" from the Application Tier.

I cannot add a picture so... here is a transcript:

*Error Encountered
TF31002: Unable to connect to this Team Foundation Server:
http://myserver:8080/tfs
Team Foundation Server Url: http://myserver:8080/tfs.
Possible reasons for failure include:
- The name, port number, or protocol for the Team Foundation Server is incorrect.
- The Team Foundation Server is offline
- The password has expired or is incorrect
Technical information (for administrator):
The remote server returned an error: (404) Not Found.*

1. I have tried changing the Service Account & password
2. I have clicked Reapply Account
3. I have tried changing the Authentication Settings
4. When I click Group Membership or Administer Security, I get the 404 error
5. I have tried changing the URL

   a. http://myserver:8080/tfs/defaultcollection

   b. http://myserver:80//

   c. http://myserver:8080

   d. http://(ipaddress):8080/tfs

   e. http://localhost:8080/tfs

Answer (score 1):

> The remote server returned an error: (404) Not Found.

If you are using `http://localhost:8080/tfs` url  and still get (404) Not Found. Then this kind of issue may related to IIS side.

First check IIS logs, if there are some useful information.

Go to IIS manager to check the TFS bindings should be such as below:

[image]

If you look into IIS manager, application pools, under TFS app pool, what identity TFS appPool is using? If you see it is set as  “ApplicationPoolIdentity” instead of **networkService** or a domain account for TFSservice,
[image]

Try below cause and resolution and see if that could solve the issue:

*Cause:*
The ApplicationPoolIdentity account did not have permissions on the content folder.

*Resolution:*
Set the permission for the Application Pool Identity (which is a virtual account) on the folder where the content is located.

The steps to do so are:

- Right click on your Site/Application in IIS Manager and select Edit
  Permissions.
- Under Security tab click Edit, then Add. Enter "IIS AppPool\", ensure that location is set to the local computer, and
  select Check Names.
- Allow this user to have modify permissions. 
  http://learn.iis.net/page.aspx/624/application-pool-identities/

Besides, you could also take a look at this similar issue here: [TFS 2010 RC, getting 404 on http://localhost:8080/tfs](https://serverfault.com/questions/112464/tfs-2010-rc-getting-404-on-http-localhost8080-tfs)

Check if it's also **UrlScan** installed and that blocked your tfs site.

Comment: I discovered that if I click on the site "Team Foundation Server" and then click "Browse *:8080 (http)" it takes me to "http://localhost:8080/default.aspx" BUT that site takes me to a site for our copier's management console.  I am not an IIS guy, so should I delete the site (don't care if the copier breaks) and rebuild it?  How do I do that?

Comment: Hi Roger, please check if you are using http redirect, you could also using this feature in ISS , check if it do the trick. More details please take a look at this blog [Detailing TFS configuration – IIS](http://blog.majcica.com/2016/03/07/detailing-tfs-configuration-iis/).

Comment: As for if you should delete the site or not, since we don't the detail environment and configuration of your environment, we could not give your an accurate advice. Better to contact your ID department. Ordinarily, we use public url in Application Tier to connect TFS server.  And the local host url should be http://localhost:8080/tfs not localhost:8080/default.aspx

Comment: Thanks Patrick, but no luck.  I followed the procedure outlined in "Detailing TFS configuration".  The Notification URL, Server URL and Web Access URL are all the same "http://<myserver>:8080/tfs"  When I test the URL I get TF31002.  I installed the HTTP redirect in IIS and set the destination to http://<myerserver>:8080/tfs.  I deleted the default site and all Application Pools that did not apply.

Comment: For this kind of  TF31002 error, we do have an official link with several resolutions to help you narrow down the root cause.  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/reference/error/tf31002-unable-connect-tfs?view=azure-devops Please kindly go though it and check  whether helps or not. Besides, you could also take a look **Event View** on your TFS server to check if there is some useful error message.

Comment: Besides, if you are using a proxy in your network environment, do not use it.  Also temporary turn off  your Firewall and check if `http://<myserver>:8080/tfs` and `http://localhost:8080/tfs` works. If localhost url still not work , guess there is some configuration issue in your side, you may try to uninstall the entire application tier. Then reinstall and configure it.  It may do the trick.

Comment: Hi@Roger , Any update on this ticket? Did you get a chance to implement the solution suggested above? Were you able to resolve?